# How to find out the optimal memory limit in a web server for a Drupal based site

Tags: drupal, php

I have a multisite Drupal based magazine sites and I would like to know is how can I choose the optimal memory limit to be set so that maximum numbers of users can access the site without affecting the speed and the server is also able to handle the requests.

Comment: Not by theory, practical info: ~16M for default drupal, ~64M drupal with common used modules (cck, views), ~96M with images or video processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to it. Install Devel Module. Enable settings for memory usage per page and execution time.

Measure the 2 parameters on different pages.

This shall give  a fair idea of the execution time and memory limit settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that for small sites, 64M gets you by.

Ideally, you want 128M.

But, performance is more than this, especially if users are logged into the site where caching doesn't happen for content.

Also, depending on your hosting environment, php.ini overrides may not be allowed in your container.

Comment: with an overall 4GB of server memory, wont 128 MB be a lot or is it fine? Its a high traffic site but has a lot of memory intensive modules like CCK, Views as well. Do you recommend increasing the server memory or use a cluster and load balancing and keep a limit of 128M?

Comment: 128M is fine, you've got plenty of memory. We could discuss via email if you'd like.

Comment: Couldnt find your email to post you the details. I have posted another question http://serverfault.com/questions/186564/ubuntu-linux-interpretation-of-top-command-result It would be kind if you could have a look and suggest something. Thanks for all your help.